# Name of this specific type of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a specific type of name for a function that requires its predecessor?
Like so: $f(x+1) = 2f(x)$.
I am using this for a report and have deduced a general function which doesn't require the predecessor but for clarification purposes I am explaining the initial function as well.
Does this function have a specific name?
If it does I would like to hear it!
Thanks!

Comment: Recurrence relation?

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying functions and numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and help with edit. Will definitely check it better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first answer states recursive is the right word to use when it involves programming when doing that bear in mind the Halting Problem also referenced in the first answer. -JBKing

The comment on the post gave the mathematical term which I was looking for namely:
Recurrence relation. -probablyme

Thanks for answering my question everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[Recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) would probably be the best word here though a base case is often necessary as otherwise there isn't any termination and what was to be computed can't be done as the program doesn't terminate as the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) could be useful to consider here. [Recurrence Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) would be the common Math term here.

[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Fibonacci_numbers) are often defined in a recursive way. The factorial of a number can be defined as a recurrence though most know of an iterative way to calculate the value of what would otherwise be seen as a recursive product: $n!=n((n-1)!), 1!=1$ in contrast to: $n!=\prod i$ for $i=1$ to $n$.

Comment: Yeah. Recursive gets linked to programming more often then not. Recurrence relation that is stated as a comment is a more mathematical term so I am going for that one. Thanks for putting me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

The formula:
$$f(x+1)=2f(x)$$

is a functional equation according to this definition:

> In mathematics, a functional equation is any equation that
>   specifies a function in implicit form. Often, the equation relates
>   the value of a function (or functions) at some point with its values
>   at other points...

Source:[Wiki-Functional_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation)

As an FYI, you could also write the function as:
$$f(x)=2^x$$

Comment: Also correct. But this specific case is called a recurrence relation which is probably also a subsection of the functional equation